# XGboost wheel for Win 7 and 32 bit and python 3.4

Tags: xgboost

Is there a simple wheel for XGboost  ML library available somewhere for Win 7 and 32 bit and python 3.4  as I couldnt find on http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#xgboost and wouldn't wanna go the Vis c++ compiler make dlls route ??
Though wheel for python 35 and 36 are available there

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Download xgboost from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#xgboost and change the python version to 3.4.
For instance xgboost‑0.6+20171121‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl becomes xgboost‑0.6+20171121‑cp34‑cp34m‑win_amd64.whl.

It works for me with python 3.4.2 and xgboost‑0.6+20171121‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl.